# Prevent ServiceReferences.ClientConfig from getting bigger and bigger

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, service-reference

We often have to re-build our service references and we noticed how the old bindings/endpoints never get deleted. It only adds the new binding and names it `Custombinding_IOurService153`.

We're working on this project from 4 PCs. Everyone has their own URL they are getting from the config file. The file is getting HUGE!

How can we prevent that? Are there any hidden options to only write the current binding/endpoint into the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ensuring that every developer's environment is similar and that the service you are referencing is hosted in a URL that doesn't change.

If your service is in a local project and is hosted in the VS Development Server make sure that you assigning it a specific port rather than letting the server to auto-assign the port to it. Then every developer will reference the service at the same URL, for example: `http://localhost:33100/OurService.svc`.

If the URL and other parameters stay the same Visual Studio will not add new endpoint configurations to ServiceReferences.ClientConfig when you update the service reference.